# App/Activity as dialog - Xposed module (Gravity Box)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, xposed-framework

It is happening for the last two days. Certain options (activities) when launched (e.g.: Mobile network settings, App uninstall), the activity is opened as an dialog and only when Gravity box is enabled in xposed framework. But I can't find a specific option in the app for controlling this feature. Is there an option for this? Or are there any other reasons/cause?

My phone is running Android jelly bean.

[image: App uninstall as dialog]
<sup>App uninstall as dialog (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: That seems like a dialog than an overlay. How did you confirm it is an overlay?

Comment: Oh. Is it so? I'm a newbie. So I don't know much about these things.

Comment: Can you disable all of your Xposed modules and leave GravityBox module enabled? Reboot and see if the problem still persist.

Comment: Yeah. It is still seen. But not until I opened Gravity Box.